# Normalising a tags table in a database for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, many-to-many, database-normalization

So I'm learning how to create a database using SQLite, and I'm struggling in trying to separate the string with comma separated values in vendor tag and vendor tagname and then align the tag numbers with the tag names.

where lets say the vendorid is incremented from 1,2,3... etc for each row.
Here is a schema

```
CREATE TABLE unnormalized(
  vendor_tag varchar(200),
  vendor_tag_name varchar(200),
  vendor_id int
  );
  
 INSERT INTO unnormalized
VALUES
('5,8,30,24','Burgers,Desserts,Fries,Salads',1),
('5','Burgers',2),
('8,42','Desserts,Mexican',3),
('1,5,30,16','American,Burgers,Fries,Sandwiches',4),
('1,5,30,16','American,Burgers,Fries,Sandwiches',5);
```

[image]

Comment: Improve your question - please show us what you've figured out so far. How do you think the table design should be? That  makes it easier for someone to chime in with how you should proceed further (if need be). Remember, we are not here to do free work for you. Don't worry about being wrong - nobody learns without making mistakes.

Comment: Post the definitions of the relevant tables that you have, not just 2 columns of a table.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. PS Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook with justification & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs.

Comment: What does "vendorid is incremented from 1,2,3... etc for each row" mean? What do "separate" & "align" mean? Why are you saying "Normalising"? What are you trying to accomplish starting with what while in what process to result in what? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Also: [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column names in your picture aren't descriptive of the column contents.

First, I would define a `Vendor` table:

```
Vendor
------
VendorID
VendorName
...
```

where `VendorID` is an auto-incrementing integer blind primary (clustering) key and `VendorName` is the name of the vendor.  Additional Vendor attributes would belong in this table.

Edited to add: You don't have any vendors in your picture, so let's make a couple of vendors up.

```
Vendor table

VendorID | VendorName
-------- | ----------
       1 | McDonald's
       2 | IHOP
```

Next, I would define a `Tag` table.

```
Tag
---
TagID
TagName
```

where `TagID` is an auto-incrementing integer blind primary (clustering) key and `TagName` is the name of the tag.

Edited to add:  Here's what the contents of the Tag table look like.

```
Tag table

TagID | TagName
----- | -------
    1 | American
    2 | Arabic
    3 | ?
    4 | Breakfast
    5 | Burgers
  ...
```

You have one row for each tag.

Finally, since the relationship between Vendor and Tag is many to many, I would define a `VendorTag` junction table.

```
VendorTag
---------
VendorTagID
VendorID
TagID
Created Timestamp
```

where `VendorTagID` is an auto-incrementing integer blind primary (clustering) key, `VendorID` is a foreign key back to the `Vendor` table, and `TagID` is a foreign key back to the `Tag` table.

You would also define a unique index on `(VendorID, TagID)` so you can retrieve the tags for a vendor fairly easily.  If you also want to retrieve the vendors for a tag, you can create another unique index on `(TagID, VendorID)`.

Edited to add: Here's what some rows of the VendorTag table might look like.

```
VendorTag table

VendorTagID | VendorID | TagID | Created Timestamp
----------- | -------- | ----- | -------------------
          1 |        1 |     4 | 2020-12-27 16:44:10
          2 |        1 |     8 | 2020-12-27 16:44:10
          3 |        1 |    10 | 2020-12-27 16:44:11
          4 |        1 |    91 | 2020-12-27 16:44:11
```

Every column of every table contains one and only one value.  That's one of the points of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  No duplicate information in the database is another point of database normalization.

Comment: I'm quite confused. So I create a separate table with tagID and and tag name. Would or can the VendorTag table contain a list of different TagId's? e.g TagId = 1,3,7,8

Comment: @HappyCamper: See my updated answer. In a normalized database, each column of each row contains one and only one value.

Comment: Thank you! This took awhile for my head to understand. I had to visualise what you said on pen and paper :) Had to do some extra research on what a junction table was

Comment: So with the VendorTag table, If I were to create a unique identified for each row, how would I link the VendorTag_id to the Vendor table? Wouldn't that still create many variables for VendorTag_id in the Vendor table?

Comment: @HappyCamper: The VendorTagID doesn't link to anything.  It's a convenient, short, unique, primary key.  None of the ID fields have any semantic meaning, other than to link tables as foreign keys.  That's why they're called blind keys.  No user should ever see them.  32-bit integers can go up to 2 billion.  If you need more rows, you can use a 64-bit integer.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - why did you add a "created timestamp" field in the "vendor" table?

Comment: @sfxedit: I added a created timestamp to the VendorTag junction table.  Usually, junction tables have create and / or update timestamps so you can tell when the junction was created or updated.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - if a column named 'openingTimes' had the following value '9:00am - 10:00pm'. Does that need to be normalised and put into a table called ‘openingHours’  with 'opening = 9:00am' and 'closing = 10:00pm'? Or is that just left untouched?

Comment: @HappyCamper: If you're just going to display opening and closing times, then you can save the String as one column.  If you're going to do any calculations with the times, save them in the database as an integer "number of minutes past midnight".

Answer (score 0):

Create a table "vendor_tags", with two columns, id and name.  In that table you would have rows like

```
5,Burgers
8,Desserts
...
```

The "id" column would serve as the primary key to that table.

There is no "vendor_id" in your example.